# How we can secure the ClientID & ClientSecret inside our remote event receivers (Inside SharePoint Provider hosted app)

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I have developed many remote event receivers and host them inside azure web apps. now the `web.config` file inside those remote event receivers contain the `ClientId` & `ClientSecret`, as follow:-

```
 <appSettings file="custom.config">
    <add key="ClientId" value="e***7" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="h***g=" />
  </appSettings>
```

Now if a hacker or an end user found those values inside the project code, then the user can control all the sites, as when we register the remote event receivers we grant them full control on the site collection.. so any advice how we can secure those details? so if someone access the source code of the RER then she/he can not view those details?

Thanks

Comment: @CallumCrowley yes i host them inside Azure web apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use an Azure Key Vault to store these credentials. You can then either access the credentials directly via your code or by having a "dummy value" in your web.config that is replaced at runtime by your application. More information can be found here:

[About Azure Key Vault](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/overview)

[Tutorial: Use a managed identity to connect Key Vault to an Azure web app in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)

[Add Key Vault to your web application by using Visual Studio Connected Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service)

**Using a managed identity to connect to a Key Vault**

Once you have [configured your web app to connect to the Key Vault](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#configure-the-web-app-to-connect-to-key-vault), you will need to update your code to retrieve the secret from the Key Vault:

Using statements:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Core;
```

Code to access the secret:

```
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
         }
    };
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://<your-unique-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential(),options);

KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("<mySecret>");

string secretValue = secret.Value;
```

Await the response:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync(secretValue);
```

Comment: but then how i can integrate my code with the Azure Key Vault?

Comment: Check out the third link, it has code examples of how to integrate the Key Vault with any .NET project.

Comment: If this answer helped, please remember to let the community know by upvoting or accepting the answer.

Comment: the problem inside this link @ https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service is that it uses a username password to access the Key Vault.. so what will happen if this password is changed?

Comment: Try the second link: https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app this tutorial shows you how to use managed identities to connect to the Key Vault rather than have credentials in your code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with examples from Microsoft.

Comment: @CallumCrowley thanks for the update now when i want to https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#configure-the-web-app-to-connect-to-key-vault what does the `<your-webapp-name>` name inside this command refer to `az webapp identity assign --name "<your-webapp-name>" --resource-group "myResourceGroup"`.. is it the azure web app name?

Comment: @CallumCrowley also will your approach break if the user we used to created the secret and to configured the web app to connect to the Key Vault,, changed/disabled/password-change?

Comment: yes, it's the web app name: https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/webapp/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_identity_assign @johnGu no it won't because you're using a managed identity to connect to the Key Vault

Comment: @CallumCrowley ok thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

The usual way for any .NET application is to use `<appSettings file="Secrets.config" >[...]</appSettings>`, and then exclude `Secrets.config` from source control using `.gitignore`. I tend to also provide a `Secrets.Example.config` file in source control, so future developers know what they need to collect.

Please be aware that the **keys will remain in the history of the source repository**, so it might be a good idea to invalidate the old keys after doing this.

It is also possible and sometimes better to set up Azure Key Vault, but this is can also be impractical/overkill in many situations.

Related article [here](https://dev.to/pdelcogliano/little-known-configuration-attributes-provide-robust-functionality-35mm).

Answer (score 1):

Uses of client secret in production environment is not advisable.

Microsoft recommend to use SSL Certificate in production environment.

Here are the steps to use it.

1. Register the app in azure ad.
2. give the app permission as per your need.
3. Get SSL certificate or Self Signed Certificate with key protected.
4. Go to certificates & secrets section and upload it the certification. after this step you will get thumbprint.
5. Go to authentication section - add platform as website and add redirect URL of app.

After this -- Your code should acquire the token using certificate.

here are the steps for this.

1. Store your App ID, Tenant ID, Thumbprint in app config or azure key vault if you want more security.
2. Read the configurable from app config file or Azure Key Vault.

for configuration and use of Azure key vault use below link

[configure azure key vault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#configure-the-web-app-to-connect-to-key-vault)

3. How to validate and read the certificate from Local machine or Azure.

•   define the scope,

```
>     //  “/.default”  indicate that _api permission is already defined in azure ad
>     var scopes = new string[] { "https://yourdomail.sharepoint.com/.default" };
```

•   here is code to acquire the token.

```
 internal static async Task<string> GetApplicationAuthenticatedClient(string clientId, string certThumprint, string[] scopes, string tenantId)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetAppOnlyCertificate(certThumprint);

        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                        .Create(clientId)
                                        .WithCertificate(certificate)
                                        .WithTenantId(tenantId)

                                        .Build();

        AuthenticationResult authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        return accessToken;
    }
```

You can refer this link for more details.

[Configure SSL Certificate in code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code)

You can refer below link how to Add a TLS/SSL certificate in Azure App Service.

[TLS/SSL certificate in Azure App Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate)

**Now coming to your questions.**

*Even if thumbprint is compromised or known to another person. He cannot use it or do any operation as he or she will require to install this certificate at his/her location with key. As Thumbprint is installed on server with private key and uploaded in azure ad which is much more secure.*

Please accept the answer and upvote it if you are satisfied.